# How could i find my application in openwith contextmenu

Tags: .net, winforms, c#-4.0

I am working on windows forms applications using c# .net 4.0. Where I have developed one application(MyPictureViewer) similar to windows Picture Viewer. where i have one browse button so user can select it and browse some pictures and open them in my App. Currently it is working fine with all options like zoom in/out, rotation, navigation, slideshow etc. Instead of direct opening of my application **MyPictureViewer**, click on Browse and open some pictures I want prior selection of images and right click on them and choose open with.. here i should find my app MyPictureViewer in contextmenu along with Windows Picture Viwer, picaso etc. How could i include my app in openwith contextmenu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this

[Writing Windows Shell Extension with .NET](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/codefx/archive/2010/09/14/writing-windows-shell-extension-with-net-framework-4-c-vb-net-part-1.aspx)

[Creating Shortcut Menu Handlers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144171%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)